# Php shortcode on wordpress causing format problems

Tags: wordpress, alignment, shortcode

Im trying to add a price table to my wordpress site but when i add my shortcode:  to index.php , everything in the body shifts itself to the left and the text size seems to increase. Is there a way to add the php shortcode without the page format changing?? Is there a code i can add to the shortcode to isolate it or something? Im TOTALLY new at this, thanks.
This is how it looks with the price table: egraphix.net

Answer (score 0):

Fix your missing and out of place div and ul tags; that's why the layout breaks. [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  egraphix.net  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//egraphix.net/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. You can ignore the unencoded ampersand (&) errors; they don't cause layout problems.